# App crashes when i check the availability of googleplayservices

Tags: android

i have included the meta-tag in my manifest file n referenced my playservices to the workspace..what could be the problem?

```
07-24 02:41:40.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1427): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
07-24 02:41:40.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.x(Unknown Source)
07-24 02:41:40.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
07-24 02:41:40.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.example.gcm.MainActivity.checkPlayServices(MainActivity.java:49)
07-24 02:41:40.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at com.example.gcm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
07-24 02:41:40.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-24 02:41:40.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1427):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
```

Comment: Consider reading the first line in the stacktrace and acting accordingly.

Comment: hey laalto before i posted it had already took time going thro the stacktrace,,here is my meta which is included in my manifest   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: Please edit the question and add relevant parts of your manifest there. For example, where exactly you have the meta-data there.

Comment: <!--manifest file--> <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4452000" /> <activity...    
        </activity>
         </application>

Comment: hey laaato got it right thanks for cheking by,,

Answer (score 0):

declare your meta tag in under application tag:-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    .................>

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="4452000" />
```

put the required integer number or reference it from the integers file

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one `meta-data` tag inside `application` tag as shown in the `logcat` you provided

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```